# Popoulate Listview: one item per record

Tags: c#

I  am trying to filter values coming from db and list them in a list view.But I think I am missing out something.The code takes a listview and a string value. Once the user click search button all the correspondent values suppose to be listed (one row per record).  But instead, two of the fields seem to be missing as shown in the image.

I am trying to debug But I coudnt find any solutions.  So how do you create one ListView item per row/record?

[image]

```
 public void AraByTel(ListView listView, string str)
  {
      SqlCommand cmd = null;
      SqlConnection con = null;



      string insertCmd = " Select DoktorId,İletisim,Sikayet from Hastalar where İletisim like '%" + str + "%'";
          try
          {
              using (con = Baglanti.Baglan())
              {
                  using (cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, con))
                  {

                      if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                      {
                          con.Open();
                      }
                      SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                      int i = 0;
                      if (dr.HasRows)
                      {

                          while (dr.Read())
                          {
                              listView.Items.Add(dr["DoktorId"].ToString());
                              listView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(dr["Sikayet"].ToString());
                              listView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(dr["İletisim"].ToString());
                             i++;
                          }
                      }
                      dr.Close();
                  }
              }
```

Comment: Aside from the issue at hand, beware of SQL injection. Also, what type of output were you expecting?

Comment: `I Really don't see a Question here` please ask a question in regards to the problem and or issue(s) that you are faced with. also what's the use or using `i++;` when you are not using `i` anywhere in your code..???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line creates and adds a new LVI for each row returned:

```
listView.Items.Add(dr["DoktorId"].ToString());
```

But then:

```
listView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(dr["Sikayet"].ToString());
listView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(dr["İletisim"].ToString());
```

These are adding subitems for all the rows to the first Item (`Items[0]`) over and over.  Since you have only 3 column headers, you can only see the first 2 subitems (you can "hide" stuff in a LV by adding subitems which have no column header - which is what your code is accidentally doing).

You probably intended `i` as an index rather than `0` but there is no real reason to manually index it:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Text = dr["DoktorId"].ToString();
// add the sub item data to this LVI
lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["Sikayet"].ToString());
lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["İletisim"].ToString());

// add the complete LVI with sub items to the control:
listView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just [databind to the listview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2008/08/20/tip-5-did-you-know-how-to-databind-a-listview-control.aspx) rather than looping in this manner and adding them.   If you do this with a SqlDataSource, you can apply [Filtering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bfya48%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) on the SqlDataSource.